# hide HTML from students

Tags: html, css, pdf

I'm teaching an HTML/CSS class and I like to give assignments where the students have to match the look of a page. The problem is that if I just give them a link to the page they can figure out exactly how I created it and copy my work. Projecting the page on a screen doesn't work well either as each student is at a different place and needs to see a different part of the page (plus they can see the URL).

I don't actually need it to be a "real" web page since they just have to match the look. For example, a PDF or image file would work fine provided it shows the entire page correctly.

I haven't found a way to create a **single** PDF page with the entire site; instead all the PDF creators want to chop the web page up into several printable pages which makes it very hard to understand what the original page actually looked like.

Similarly, I haven't found a way to capture a (very long and skinny) image of the page. Screen shot tools only capture the visible part of the page.

Can anyone think of a way I can accomplish this? Bonus points if it's "live" so I can show off Javascript stuff.

Comment: So I take it Chrome's "Save as PDF" functionality won't suffice...? http://i.imgur.com/2MHDT2E.png

Comment: I use FireFox with a screen snapshot plugin that can capture also the invisibly scrolled (entire) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "ExtensionAwesome Screenshot" is a chrome extension [ExtensionAwesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en)

So you can save a screenshot of your entire page, partial page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Chrome extension called Webpage Snapshot. It will make a screenshot of the entire page.

Here is the link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot-captur/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en

Comment: This looks great. @jcry87 beat you to it so I marked his correct, but this is a great answer too. Thanks!